# Contents are overlapping in ionic app

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to create app with Header, Tabs and List. but contents are not are in there proper place. I have tried multiple options but nothing worked so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable center">
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="button button-clear icon ion-home"></button>
        </div>
        <h1 class="title">Test App</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="button button-clear icon ion-calendar"></button>
        </div>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="has-header">
        <div class="tabs-striped tabs-top tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
          <div class="tabs">
            <a class="tab-item active" href="#">
              Test
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item" href="#">
              Favorites
            </a>
            <a class="tab-item" href="#">
              Settings
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="has-tabs">
        <ion-list>
          <ion-checkbox ng-model="filter.blue">Red</ion-checkbox>
          <ion-checkbox ng-model="filter.yellow">Yellow</ion-checkbox>
          <ion-checkbox ng-model="filter.pink">Pink</ion-checkbox>
        </ion-list>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is screenshot of output[image: Output]. please help if possible.

Comment: maybe try making a sub-header and put the tabs in that? I noticed that ionic uses a lot of absolute positioning for headers.

Comment: do u want to get ion-list under any one of the tab..?if u want to show..list and tab !

Comment: I want header -> then Tabs ->then List. one after one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
<div class="tabs-top  tabs-background-positive tabs-color-light">
<div class="tabs "style="top:0px;">
```

also change :

```
<ion-list class="list has-header">
```

hope this help u..!